# How antivirus can able to open the File in read mode even though it is share denied for reading and writing

Tags: c++, windows, file

Let me explain in detail:
In my application I am using `fopen()` with `_SH_DENYRW` (deny read/write mode) and after this, anti virus can able to open the file in read mode using `CreateFile`. So due to this some times other Windows functions like `SetEndOfFile` fails in my application.

Answer (score 2):

Because the AV software is hooking in below the official OS (or C library) level, and thus ignores/bypasses the "you shouldn't open this file" restriction.

However, I'd say it's irrellevant, since the AV software would be seriously flawed if there was an easy way to bypass it.

If AV is causing problems, you have three choices:

1. Stop using that AV software.
2. report it as a bug to the AV software and hope they fix it (sometime soon).
3. fix your software so that it works [whatever that involves].

Your decision will of course be influenced by the number of installations of the AV software and the number of installations of your software, respectively.

(An option not mentioned above is of course to contact the AV software company with the question as to "how do I work around this" - I'm a little surprised that they have problems that affect such trivial things as `SetEndOfFile` - it may not be the most common operation, but certainly not one of those that only 0.1% of all software uses, which may "not be found" by the testing of the AV software)

Comment: In practice, you see that multiple AV companies manage to screw up basic operations. However, this shows up as intermittent failures, presumably due to race conditions. You won't have 100% of `SetEndOfIle` calls fail, but 0.1%. This explains why so often in software installation troubleshooting, there's the advice to disable AV.